# Two Javascript functions don't work together

Tags: javascript

I wanted to write some javascript functions for my theme and I'm a newbie in Javascript (So, Please don't laugh at me).

The first function is about navbar that when you scroll 400px, navbar will show from top. And second is about "goto-up" button.

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 400 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 400) {
        document.getElementById("goup").style.bottom = "0";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("goup").style.bottom = "-100px";
    }
};
window.onscroll = function() {goupFunction();};

function goupFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 300 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 300) {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
    }
};
```

These two don't work together. I need your help.
@Pedram, Fixed my problem.
Thanks xD ( I added the second function to the first function and now those works together.)

Comment: Please click the `<>` button and create a [mcve] - it is not clear what the two functions are supposed to do

Comment: No one  laugh at you. But why you didn't use one function?

Comment: @Pedram I love you xD (Damet garm). You fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you assign to `window.onscroll`, you overwrite the event handler. Instead, use [`window.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and/or put both calls in one function.

So remove all `window.onscroll = ..` lines and add:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    scrollFunction();
    groupFunction();
};
```